# Proof that $\exp (-\frac{1}{x})$ is Lipschitz continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Prove that $\exp (-\frac{1}{x})$ is Lipschitz continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

My idea for any $x,y > 0$, we know that $\max\{\exp (-\frac{1}{x}), \exp (-\frac{1}{y})\}\leq 1 $

Could I simply choose my Lipschitz constant as $L:=2$, since

$\lvert \exp (-\frac{1}{x})- \exp (-\frac{1}{y})\rvert \leq 2$ by the triangle inequality? I then however have no dependency on $x,y$. Any ideas?

Comment: Proof that the derivative is bounded on the given interval then lipschitz continuity follows directly

Comment: Sniped ........

Answer (score 1):

As, $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $(0,\infty) $.

So, using mean value theorem on $f$ over $[x,y]$, $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(z)| |x-y| $ for some $z\in (x,y) $, where $x,y$ arbitrarily choosen from $(0,\infty) $

Now as, $f'(x)= \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2} $ ,it is bounded on $(0,\infty) $,

So, , $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |f'(z)| |x-y| \le M |x-y| $